# $T$-invariant Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

If $T$ is time-reversal transformation $t\mapsto -t$, Why do $T$-invariant Bloch Hamiltonians obey $$H(-k) = T H(k) T^{-1}$$ and not $$H(k) = T H(k) T^{-1}$$ Somehow I understand the word "invariant" as being unchanged under a transformation. As the way an operator $O$ on a Hilbert space transforms as $O\mapsto P O P^{-1}$ where $P$ is the transformation, I don't see why it is usually the former and not the latter which you find in literature (for example [Hasan and Kane 2010](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.82.3045)).

Comment: Time-reversal is an anti-unitary operator (not linear). Does it answer your question?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. It doesn't answer my question yet, at least not explicitly so. What kind of condition is more important, from which the first equation in my original question stems? Is it the invariance of the absolute value of a transition amplitude? If so, why is the _Hamiltonian_ called invariant?

Comment: it is the same thing...

Comment: Found a discussion that shows why this is true in Chapter 4 of a book by Bernevig: http://press.princeton.edu/titles/10039.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the total $H = \sum_k H_k$ invariant under time reversal

Comment: what's wrong with this answer? I think it prfectly points out the OP's confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes invariant is used to mean covariant. If you have an Hamiltonian in momentum-space representation, the time inversion changes the sign of velocities, and therefore of the momentum. As a consequence of this fact it turns out that a time reversal in quantum mechanics must be implemented by an antilinear unitary operator, as shown by Wigner (1931).